# Jest SpyOn in a Reactjs functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to SpyOn a function inside a reactJS functional component. I have seen a few answers and came to know about the procedure where we pass the functions as props to our component. But that method doesn't work out for me. So I tried using
 `const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, "sampleFunctionName");`
As Expected it throws an error saying `sampleFunctionName` is undefined as App.prototype doesn't contain it. So to overcome this I added `sampleFunctionName` to App.prototype as `App.prototype.sampleFunctionName = jest.fn()` and tried spying it as

```
wrapper = shallow(<App {...props} />);
wrapper.find("#btn-id").simulate("click")
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Now the problem is that the number of times spy is called is always zero. So i would like to know if what I've tried is correct or any other method to spy a function inside a classless component

Here is an example to demonstrate the above-mentioned requirement:

```
function App(props){
  function save(){
    //contains the code for api calls and store changes
  }
  return(
    <Button id = "btn-id" onClick = {save}>Name</Button>
  )
}
```

And the testfile would be like:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import {App} from './App'
describe('desc',() =>{
      ...
      const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, "save");
      //using the above spy says "save" is undefined so added this line before using spy
      // App.prototype.save = jest.fn()

      wrapper = shallow(<App {...props} />);
      wrapper.find("#btn-id").simulate("click")
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: Please share a sample code from your component. May be you are doing the test the wrong way

Comment: You shouldn't spy on the thing you're trying to test. What does that method *do*, what's the *behaviour* to test? Give a [mre] of test *and* component.

Comment: I just added the information needed would you give it a look once

Comment: try console.log() in your real code and see whether the console.log() has been called

Comment: yep, it's working for console.log

Comment: What does the `save` function in your `App` component do?

Comment: How did you spy? Don't see the code

Comment: @slideshowp2 I added the spy part. Would you have a look at it once

Answer (score 2):

You can't mock or spy on `save` function, it's a private function in the `App` constructor function, **NOT a method of App instance, which means `save` function doesn't exist at the prototype of App**. You should mock or spy on the function inside the `save` function, the function/method which makes api calls for your case. Here is the unit test solution:

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  function save() {
    // contains the code for api calls and store changes
    console.log('You should spy or mock the function which make the api calls');
  }
  return (
    <button id="btn-id" onClick={save}>
      Name
    </button>
  );
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { App } from './';

describe('61174416', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const props = {};
    const wrapper = shallow(<App {...props} />);
    wrapper.find('#btn-id').simulate('click');
    expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61174416/index.test.tsx (8.332s)
  61174416
    ✓ should pass (19ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866
    You should spy or mock the function which make the api calls

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.395s
```

Replace the `console.log` with the function or method which makes the api calls.

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61174416

Comment: thanks for the answer but if we want to test for cases where we have no console log in functions, I found a workaround. Since we can't spyon Save function we can search for button as wrapper.find(Button), then we can use onClick in it's props as Wrapper.find(Button).prop(onClick), will give access to test all side effects

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could provide some code where you show us how you do this

Comment: why does everyone keep using this console log answeR?

Comment: `console.log` just a demonstration, it can be anything. You need to implement different testing strategies based on different implementations